# How to transfer my existing Photo and video from Phone memory to SD card in my Windows 8 Phone?

Tags: settings, micro-sd

I have Nokia Lumia 720 Windows Phone which supports SD card. Before I purchased SD card I took some Photos and Videos but now I have purchased it and configured it to store all new photos, videos and songs.

But how can I transfer my existing photo, video, Mp3 from phone memory to SD card?

Comment: Good question, I think you only can do this in the PC.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Windows Phone 8 currently has no app to move all of your music, photos and video from the internal storage to SD memory card - you must do this manually.

**Move the files to your PC**

1. Connect your Windows Phone 8 device to your PC with a USB cable. Open Windows Explorer, your device should show up (eg. Nokia Lumia 820).
2. When you browse the device you'll see **Phone** and **SD card**. Expand **Phone** and you'll see the Pictures, Videos, etc.
3. Go into each folder and select all the sub-folders then move them to your PC (eg. a temporary folder on your desktop).
4. When that's done, double check that the Pictures, Videos and Music folders on the **Phone** are empty.

**Move the files onto the SD card**

1. Browse the **SD card** and you'll see Music, Pictures and Videos.
2. Copy the sub-folders from your desktop into the equivalent folders on the **SD card**.

*Tested on a Lumia 820 with 4GB SD card on Windows 8 Pro.*

Comment: OK I'm going to try this with my Lumia 720 and Windows 7

Comment: You shouldn't have any issues with Windows 7, the Lumia 720 will still show up in Windows Explorer.